# override value in systemd unit

Tags: nixos

I am learning NixOS and as an experiment I am trying to override an attribute in the systemd service `getty@tty1.service`. Specifically, I would like to set `TTYVTDisallocate=no` in the `[Service]` section of the unit file for that service. In a traditional linux distro, I would create a file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/custom.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
TTYVTDisallocate=no
```

which will make systemd override the attribute in unit. How do I do that in NixOS? I tried to add the following to my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`

```
environment.etc = {
  "systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/custom.conf" = {
    text = ''
      [Service]
      TTYVTDisallocate=no
    '';
  };
};
```

but I get the following error:

```
# nixos-rebuild switch
[some omitted uninteresting lines]
mkdir: cannot create directory '/nix/store/ci27glj5m2alpsw6g50plhvx24x4w711-etc/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d': Permission denied
error: builder for '/nix/store/az3m4d3318wn459124mz31m7gpvvq5nw-etc.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/dgrqmyyzdb4pv6p36m46xayk6sfnr604-nixos-system-nixos-22.11.1198.913a47cd064.drv' failed to build
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? or some alternative way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding the following to my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
  systemd.packages = [                     
    (pkgs.runCommandNoCC "systemd-getty-service-overrides" {                          
      preferLocalBuild = true;                                                        
      allowSubstitutes = false;                                                       
    } ''                                                                              
      mkdir -p $out/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
      printf "[Service]\nTTYVTDisallocate=no\n" > $out/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/custom.conf
    '')                  
  ];
```

It's not an ideal solution (I was hoping to find something more generic), but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```hs
systemd.services."getty@tty1" = {
  overrideStrategy = "asDropin";
  serviceConfig.TTYVTDisallocate = "no";
};
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)